# Dynamic Master Page with access to variables in both masters

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, master-pages

I have two master pages , one is for Desktop and the other is for Mobile , 
and depends on the device I use **dynamically** either the Desktop or the Mobile master page.
But I can't access the variables from the child ASPX page in the master pages.

The ASPX Code behind :

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "MobileMasterPage.master";
    }
    else
    {
        this.MasterPageFile = "MasterPageDesktop.master";
    }           
}
```

And in both master pages there are the variables

```
public int TinyMceWidth { get; set; }
public int TinyMceHeight { get; set; }
```

But I can't access those two variables from the code behind of the ASPX :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Master.TinyMceWidth = 1000; // Can't access 
    Master.TinyMceHeight = 1000; // Can't access    
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: MVC you can use the areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acess it like this.

```
var master = (Site1)Page.Master;
master.TinyMceWidth = 1000;
```

`Site1` is the class name of the Master Page

```
public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
}
```

So because you have 2 masters, you will need to create 2 variables for them

```
var masterMobile = (Site2)Page.Master;
```